# What kind of bands exercise are appropriate for mini stepper

Tags: exercise, weight-loss, cardio, training

I bought a mini stepper with bands.
But I am curious:

**What kind of band movements are appropriate for the mini steppers in general?**

- I saw this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfkpdMXEzuQ, but this hand movement looks different from the one I was told in shop. Am I free to do this kind of exercise like on the video too?  In the shop they didn't mention such movement - rather what they mentioned looked more something like this with straight arms:

[image]

**I know that bands are bands and are mostly same, but maybe you can do one kind of band movement with one model and no with another, or am I overthinking?**

My model don't have this in docs.

Or I can go to youtube and pick any mini stepper band movement from there?

Comment: You're over-thinking ;) You're free to do whatever you want. Who's going to stop you?

Comment: @DaveNewton OK thanks forgot to finish sign up. Yeah no because I heard you must properly to some exercises not to damage yourself.

Comment: All exercises should be done with reasonable form.

Comment: @DaveNewton So if I follow that video, that is reasonable. I just thought maybe those band exercises on that video are for that stepper model etc.

Answer (score -4):

The movement in the photo is good for Muscles behind the arm, but the movement we see in the video is good for Muscles Forearm movements. You can do both. You would see which movement you need and which  side of arm you want to be strengthen and powerful